# bibliography showing chapter 1 as footnote

Tags: fancyhdr

The following is my thesis

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage{caption}
%\usepackage{subcaption} \usepackage{subfigmat} % You can either use subfigmat or subcaption
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{Systemic Crisis Transmission: Visualizing
Vulnerability} \setlength\headheight{15pt} \fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage} \fancyfoot[LO,CE]{chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot[CO,RE]{Raisul Islam} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\usepackage{ltablex} \keepXColumns \usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xcolor} \captionsetup{font=footnotesize}

\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} %
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex} % \addbibresource{ref.bib}

\title{Thesis} \author{raisul.islam} \date{February 2020}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle \input{chapter/titlepage} \input{chapter/Abstract}
\newpage \input{chapter/Literature Review} \newpage \bibliography{ref}


\end{document}
```

My literature review is chapter 1. So the footnote with fancyhdr shows chapter 1. That's fine.

BUT MY BIBLIOGRAPHY SECTION FOOTNOTE SHOWS CHAPTER 1. HOW TO FIX IT SOIBLIOGRAPHY SECTION DOES NOT SHOW HEADER OR FOOTER AS OTHER CHAPTERS?

Comment: Maybe with empty commands, like `\fancyfoot[LO,CE]{}`? Or `\pagestyle{plain}`?

Comment: I jusst had to put  \chapter{}...fixed it...thnx

Comment: Put your solution as the answer.

Comment: Ok, just put \pagestyle{empty} 
\bibliography{ref} and no page numbers will be shown in bibliography

Answer (score 1):

```
\begin{document}
%\maketitle \input{chapter/titlepage}
\input{chapter/Abstract}
\newpage
\input{chapter/Literature Review}
\newpage
\bibliography{ref}
\pagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

should solve the problem.

Comment: Please, is it possible to see how have you solved the problem?

Comment: Thank you. Just put \pagestyle{empty} before the section begins, Ora’s the top line of the file. In my case, I used that option before \bibliography.